# SQL Server + Linux + VB6 + Wine + Adodb.Recordset +Error 430

Tags: sql-server, linux, automation, vb6, wine

- I have a VB6.0 app running in Wine 5.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- I have a SQL Server database on a remote Linux server (also Ubuntu 18.04 LTS)
- I have tested connectivity to the database in Wine using ODBC Manager
- I have tested connectivity to the database in Linux using Azure Data Studio
- The VB application references the Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.8 library

I create an ADODB.Connection object (early binding and late binding tested), and an ADODB.Recordset object.

---

```
With rec1
    .ActiveConnection = gConn1
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = 1
    .Source = "Select * from [tblUsers] WHERE Username='" & XXXXX & "'"
    .Open
End With
```

---

I am getting an Automation error, Error 430, "Runtime error '430' class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface.

Please help, this is the last hurdle in a very long project.

Comment: If you've previously tested with both late & early binding - presumably on a different computer - there must be some difference in configuration on the computer where it fails. Presumably, some DLL is not registered properly.

Comment: IMHO, you project is about to get longer, because if the query you've shown here is representative of how you're querying the database, you're open to SQL injection attacks. Also, why are you implementing _anything_ new with VB6 running on Wine in the year 2020?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I am currently attempting to identify any DLL registration errors. Its a local solution, not a web application. Its a legacy VB app developed in 2013, and we do not have a nudget to go for a web driven solution currently. We want to simply host the solution on Linux untill, in a few years, we have a budget for re-developing the entire solution, or porting, to the web.

Comment: Have you tried running your VB6 program on Windows, connecting to the remote Linux SQL Server? I would be suspicious about the Wine part personally. AFAICR SQL Server is supported on Linux so that part should work.  If the Wine part does prove to be the issue I think I would consider running the VB6 in Windows, in a virtual machine or Docker container if necessary. I don't think ADO uses ODBC so the test with ODBC manager on Wine is not exhaustive.

Comment: I believe you may have hit the nail on the head so to speak. Just because I have an ODBC connection does not mean the ADODB.Connection object will be interpreted correctly? So I need to find out why the object model is not supported in Wine?

Comment: The VB app is currently running on 10 user machines running Windows 7 with the SQL Server database hosted on a Linux 'server'. Used to be hosted on a Windows Server before migration to Linux. The network side of things seem to be in place, this seems to be related to an object model that is not exposed?

Comment: Post the connect string used by ADODB.Connection